# How do achieve a frame around image

Tags: iphone, image-processing, uiimage

I like the way this (http://shakeitphoto.com/) application puts a border around the image.. i would like to do something similar in my application but not sure how should I go about doing it.

Any ideas on how given a UIImage can I wrap a frame around it?

Comment: post screens if you want people to look at something. No one is going to download an app just to see what a question is about.  
Edit: also, there are quite a few questions about this already on stack overflow. check some of them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From that website, it appears you want a border with a shadow. There's 2 reasonable options, 3 if you don't care about the shadow.

If you don't care about the shadow, you can just do something like

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> // this should be at the top

// inside your view layout code
myImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor
myImageView.layer.borderWidth = 5;
```

This will give you a 5-pixel white border inset into the view, layered on top of the view's contents (e.g. the image). What it won't give you is a shadow. If you want the shadow, there's 2 other options.

You could just create an image that includes the border and the shadow, and nothing else. Just make everything else alpha-transparent. Then you can simply layer this image on top of the one you want to display (either with 2 imageviews, or by creating a third image out of the 2). This should work fine, but it won't scale to different image sizes. In the case of the linked app, the image size is always the same so they could be using this.

The other option is to simply draw the border and shadow on top of your image in a new image. Here's a bit of sample code that will do this - it creates a new image the same size as your original, but with a white, shadowed border:

```
- (UIImage *)borderedImage:(UIImage *)image {
    // the following NO means the new image has an alpha channel
    // If you know the source image is fully-opaque, you may want to set that to YES
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, image.scale);
    [image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    const CGFloat shadowRadius = 5;
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(ctx, 0, shadowRadius, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
    CGRect rect = (CGRect){CGPointZero, image.size};
    const CGFloat frameWidth = 5;
    rect = CGRectInset(rect, frameWidth / 2.0f, frameWidth / 2.0f);
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:rect];
    path.lineWidth = frameWidth;
    [path stroke];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    // note: getting the new image this way throws away the orientation data from the original
    // You could create a third image by doing something like
    //   newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage.CGImage scale:newImage.scale orientation:image.orientation]
    // but I am unsure as to how orientation actually affects rendering (if at all)
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

(note: this code has not been compiled and could contain bugs)